# set Monday is first day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft sql server and in the sql server by default first day of week is Sunday but I need to set it Monday is the first day of week.

Comment: https://database.guide/set-datefirst-set-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-sql-server/

Comment: Ideally (to my mind) you write `DATEFIRST` agnostic code instead - find ways using e.g. "known good" dates to avoid depending on *particular* values returned by e.g. `DATEPART`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`SET DATEFIRST { number }`

```
number
1      Monday
2      Tuesday
3      Wednesday
4      Thursday
5      Friday
6      Saturday
7      Sunday
```

Here the link to the official docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4):

This sets the first day of the week to Monday

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SET DATEFIRST` like following.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://database.guide/set-datefirst-set-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this command :

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

See this [post](https://database.guide/set-datefirst-set-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-sql-server/)